# HTML Image Refresh works fine, but adding PHP breaks something

Tags: php, javascript

I have this HTML that works very well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<script language="JavaScript"><!--
    function refreshIt() {
        if (!document.images) return;
        var myImage = document.getElementById('signals');
        myImage.src = 'http://lessthanrandom.com/screencast/signals.jpg?' + Math.random();
        setTimeout('refreshIt()', 900000); // refresh every 60 seconds
        //setTimeout('refreshIt()', 1800000); // refresh every 1/2 hour
    }
//--></script>



<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0}
html, body {height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden}
table {height:100%;width:100%;table-layout:static;border-collapse:collapse}
iframe {height:100%;width:100%}

.header {border-bottom:1px solid #000}
.content {height:100%}
</style>
</head>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('refreshIt()', 900000)">
<table>
  <tr><td class="content">
    <img src="http://lessthanrandom.com/screencast/signals.jpg" width="100%" id="signals" name="signals"></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If I add the following PHP above this and change to a PHP file, the image displays, but does not refresh. I'm new to PHP and Javascript.

```
    <?php
include_once "/home/lesadmin/public_html/wp-load.php";
if (current_user_can("access_s2member_level1"))
{ 
}
else
    exit("Must have a valid membership to view this content.");
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in the console? What is in wp-load.php?

Comment: It seems like your problem is with the current_user_can function. I think is exiting the page on the refresh. You can print the message instead of using exit, and see what happens. Do you have the errors display activated on php.ini?

Comment: I will investigate the javascript console and my php.ini...